# How to use the "find where" SailsJS blueprint route?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sails.js, waterline

## Use Case

I'd like to create a complex query **with more than one criterion** using the SailsJS "[Find Where](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Find.html)" blueprint route. However, I am unable to use the *equals* comparator and the *and* condition successfully. I couldn't find adequate documentation on how to implement the *Find Where* route, so I worked through the [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-criteria/blob/master/lib/filters/where.js) and came up with the following scenarios.

## Question

Using the SailsJS *Find Where* Blueprint Route, how does one implement:

- the *equality* comparison
- the *and* condition

### Success Scenarios

The following scenarios will return the appropriate response:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/user?name=fred
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"startsWith":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"endsWith":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"contains":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"like":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"or":[{"name":{"startsWith":"fred"}}]}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"or":[{"name":{"startsWith":"fred"}},{"path":{"endsWith":"fred"}}]}
```

### Failure Scenario

The following scenarios return an empty response:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"equals":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"=":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"equal":"fred"}}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"and":[{"name":{"startsWith":"fred"}}]}
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"and":[{"name":{"startsWith":"fred"}},{"path":{"endsWith":"fred"}}]}
```

Comment: FYI: In case you're trying to search for date values, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1743).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use "and" queries you use the query string syntax and chain criteria together using the ampersand character. For more advanced queries like `OR` or complex operators its best to write a controller action. If you decide to stick with blueprints you can use most valid Waterline queries encoded as JSON.

For simple queries you use the query string method. The following would build an "and" query for name and school.

```
http://localhost:1337/api/user?name=fred&school=foo
```

To chain together more advanced operators the following should work:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/user?where={"name":{"startsWith":"fred"},"path":{"endsWith":"fred"}}
```